# Unity>How to make a Box Collider( or any other collider) fits the gameObject perfectly?

Tags: unity

I have downloaded and imported the Robot Kyle model in Unity 3D...and the problem with me is I want to add a Box or Capsule Collider to it...but I can't fit it perfectly...

So what shall I do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use a mesh collider  and enable convex check box :)